# Permission to publish a figure from a Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, attribution

The figure I want to publish in my book is on this address which I have found in @thomij's answer on Chemistry Stack Exchange: [Difference between shells, subshells and orbitals](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18466/difference-between-shells-subshells-and-orbitals).

But I couldn't find the email address for contacting him.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/attribution-required/),[this](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#how-do-i-properly-attribute-material-offered-under-a-creative-commons-license) and [this](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) also.

Answer (score 5):

All user-contributed content on Stack Exchange sites is licensed to you under the terms of [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). This means that you may

- copy
- redistribute
- reformat
- adapt

the material as you wish, for any purpose including commercial usage, *as long as you*

- give appropriate credit <sup>1</sup>
- apply the same CC BY-SA 3.0 license to your redistributions or adaptations.

There is no need to contact the copyright holder (the author) to do any of these things.

---

<sup>1</sup> "appropriate credit" is defined as "If supplied, you must provide the name of the creator and attribution parties, a copyright notice, a license notice, a disclaimer notice, and a link to the material. CC licenses prior to Version 4.0 also require you to provide the title of the material if supplied, and may have other slight differences."

Comment: What if the figure in question isn't the author's to redistribute under CC BY-SA? E.g. I download or scan an all-rights-reserved photo and add it to this answer with nobody's permission. The author in question says it's the diagram they use, but they make no claim to it.

Comment: What matters here is the owner of the figure, not someone who republished it, @doppelgreener. If the original author / copyright holder didn't license it under CC BY-SA, then it's not licensed under CC BY-SA. Always best to research ownership.

Comment: @Shog9 That's what I suspected; thanks for confirming. That suggests there's actually some digging work necessary to verify the license on that figure or the post author's right to license it under CC BY-SA, since the post author didn't specify anything about license status of the figure.

Comment: Nice bit is, if you follow the attribution rules properly you don't make the problem any *worse*. That is, if you assume the author of that post created the diagram (because he didn't give attribution to anyone else), and give him attribution, there's a breadcrumb trail of sorts for whoever references *your* use of the image. If it later turns out the image was someone else's, that information can be added.